# how to fix GET net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, http, server

i am very very new to backend and express js. I wanted to fetch data from my rest api but it is sending this error net::ERR_FAILED.

```js
//my api

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.send("hello world!!!")
})
const videos = {
    "source": "....com",
    "url": "...com"
}
app.get("/api/home", (req, res)=>{
    res.send(videos)
})
app.listen(3500, ()=>console.log("listening at port 3500..."))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="init()">hey</button>
        
        <script>
            function init(){
                const url = "http://localhost:3500/api/home"
                fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then(result=>{
                    console.log(result)
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to console log the data `videos` from the api when i click the button, but its not working.

it even says:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3500/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.html:12 GET http://localhost

Comment: Check [this](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) out. It's from the official Express docs. You can just enable all origins while you're developing/testing your backend and then, prior to production release, set your domain name there. That will only allow traffic from that origin to be further processed by your backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your front-end service address port and back-end service address port are different, [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is triggered. That's why you got the error in the console of the browser.

In order to enable CORS, we can use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.

Or, use a [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) to proxy your API to the target server.

Frontend => local HTTP server => target server.

Answer (score 2):

`net::ERR_FAILED 200` Has happened to me in Windows when I had near to 0 free space on the disk C:, I was not able to load my page and the error appeared especially for *.mp4 file which had dozens megabytes of size and the web app tried to preloaded it.

Comment: Same problem on MacOS when free space is very low (near 2GB). I was not able to load a wasm file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
Check /etc/hosts on your machine and
try to add (if does not exists)
127.0.0.1   localhost